# Сохранить большой JSON файл PHP

Tags: php, массивы, база-данных, json

Создал массив товаров, данных по ним много. Всего товаров 8235. Как можно записать такой массив?

Этим вариантом смог записать 3 товара

```
$filename = 'dump.json';
$file = fopen($filename,'w+');
fwrite($file, $json);
fclose($file);
```

Другой вариант смог сохранить 350 товаров

```
$file = fopen("dump2.json", "w+"); 
$pieces = str_split($json, 1024 * 4); 
foreach ($pieces as $piece) { 
  fwrite($file, $piece, strlen($piece)); 
} 
fclose($file);
```

В PHP.ini менял значения max_execution_time, max_input_time, upload_max_filesize, post_max_size, но результата не дало

Comment: Бред какой-то. что значит "смог записать 3 товара"? джейсон получается валидный или нет? при чем здесь  upload_max_filesize, post_max_size? проблема **точно** в сохранении, а не в чем-то ещё?

Comment: Валидный. Связано скорее всего с объемом записываемых данных. Если записываю много товаров разом, файл просто не появляется на сервере

Comment: рекомендую проверить массив ПЕРЕД записью. и с удивлением обнаружить, что в нём всего три элемента.

Comment: Это понятно. Я записываю в массив 3 товара, сохранение идет, записываю 4й, ничего не происходит

Comment: что, у вас `$data = [1,2,3]; file_put_contents("x.json", json_encode($data))` работает, а когда меняете на `[1,2,3,4]` то перестает?

Comment: да, только вместо чисел массивы данных

Comment: А места свободного хватает на диске?

Comment: 20GB. Может мне оперативки не хватило? На vds меньше гига, доступно 2/3, итоговый файл по размерам должен выйти ~300мб

Comment: я так понимаю Вы же не руками `json` создаете? Явно получаете его откуда-то - например из `БД`. Если это так, то скорее всего у Вас проблема при получении и формировании массива, либо не хватает выделенной памяти под переменную в которой и сидит итоговый `json`. Попробуйте сохранить сформированный `json` прямым запросом из `БД` прямо на диск. Тот же `mySQL` это позволяет.

Comment: Надо включить вывод всех ошибок. Не может так быть, чобы файл не создался и ошибок никаких нет

Comment: Что происходит когда НЕ сохраняется? Ошибки какие-то? Что-то в логах?